# A solution of an electrostatic problem without definition of flux

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gauss-law, coulombs-law

I have this problem:

[image]

---

The figure shows the electric field lines around a system of three charges $q_1$, $q_2$ and $q_3$. The central charge have a value of $q_2=-10.0\,\mu\mathrm C$. Find the value of the charge $q_1=q_3$.

**My solution:**

Using the 8 lines exit from the charge $q_1$, 16 lines enter $q_2$. Since 8 is half of 16 and the number of incoming or outgoing lines is proportional to the intensity of the charge, the intensity of $q_1$ is half of $q_2$, i.e. $5.00$ mC. The same applies to $q_3$.

**My question:**

Is there an alternative way using Coloumb's law to solve the same problem?

Comment: But the doubling of field lines is due to the fact that there are two charges supplying lines to $q_2$, right? By your argument you change the value of the charges by just adding or taking away other charges. You will always have the same amount of lines coming off of/coming onto charges in diagrams like these. The number of lines alone doesn't tell you anything.

Comment: @AaronStevens Yes! $q_1$ and $q_3$ are positive charges as the lines of force are entering on $q_2$. I'm sorry to ask, but is my question clear? Thank you very much.  I do not want it to be unclear. I have seen only the figure but my reasoning is based on the concept of flow through a Gaussian surface, since the flow of the electric field is not also the number of lines of force or field crossing that surface.

Comment: Yes you are right to think of Gauss's law. What I am saying is that the fact that the number of field lines doesn't determine the relative field strength. Field lines start on positive charges and end on negative charges, so no matter what the values of the charges are, you will always have double the amount of lines entering $q_2$ than coming off of $q_1$

Comment: @AaronStevens You're right! ok! This morning I have thought if the question could be solved by Coulomb's law. I did some tests but I did not come to a physical conclusion (with the formulas) corrected by setting a Cartesian reference system fixed on the $q_1$ charge.

Comment: Yeah this question isn't answerable (to my knowledge) without knowing the conventions your text uses for diagrams like these. Typically the density of field lines indicates the strength of the field at some point, but this also requires knowing the spatial scale of the diagram as well.

Comment: @AaronStevens I have only these informations. Sorry.

Comment: One feature that hasn't been discussed is that since there are no fieldlines leaving the region, the total charge is zero (so q1+q2+q3=0). A Gaussian surface enclosing them would have no net fieldlines piercing the sufrace. Since the unknown charges are placed symmetrically, you can deduce q1=q3. To use Coulomb's Law, you would probably have to head off toward infinity and conclude that looking back that the net charge is zero. So, I don't think Coulomb's Law would be helpful here.

Comment: @robphy In the meantime, I thank you with due respect for your precious comment. As far as I remember, I have taken the text of this exercise in a section where it is also about the law of Coulomb; for this reason I have come to the doubt. Thank you.